# Equivalence between strictly increasing integer sequences and decision problems

Tags: discussion, code-golf, tags, challenges

I have noticed that [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) questions are often looking at strictly increasing integer sequences. For these types of sequences, the [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) task of outputting the values in the sequence is largely equivalent to the [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) of deciding whether a number appears in the sequence.

This suggests the option of having an [increasing-integer-sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/increasing-integer-sequence) tag, for which both [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) answers and [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) answers are valid.

Should we do that? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is not necessary for the elements of the sequence to be integers for the equivalence to hold, so [tag:increasing-sequence] would be a simpler and more general name for the same concept.

Comment: @bsoelch while it doesn't have to be integers, it has to be discrete (so you can do something like `for element in range: if valid: print(element)`). It could work with strings, perhaps, but I can't think of any other data types which has that naturally

Comment: As far as I can remember every decidable set is also recursively enumerable.  Maybe "increasing" is not the right word. [tag:enumerable-set] should cover the full concept (but may not be as easy to understand)

Comment: @bsoelch suppose the sequence is of positive rationals. It's not possible to convert an arbitrary decision procedure to a sequence, nor vice versa. You need a specific enumeration, and you can't enumerate the rationals in increasing order

Comment: Even if the question allows any order it isn't equivalent, since not all recursively enumerable sets are decidable

Comment: Do we really want a tag with implied rules? It's common for a sequence from a challenge to be increasing, and I wouldn't expect it to allow membership oracles just because it's tagged with a descriptive name.

Comment: @xnor What I'm saying is that for increasing integer sequences it might make sense to allow membership oracles by default, just like [tag:sequence] has default I/O methods, and if it doesn't fit some challenge the author can exclude it.

Comment: @CommandMaster I wouldn't expect or like that as a default for challenges I post, and I don't think most posters would. I guess I can post an answer to see if the votes agree with this or not.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is accepted as a default / tag, feel free to include it as an allowance in any of your own future challenges, as it is an interesting idea IMO

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### This isn't a good default

I wouldn't expect or want for my [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges to allow membership-oracle solution by default just because the sequence is increasing. While [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) allows various formats by default, what they share in common is outputting elements of the sequence, which the [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) version does not. Yes, a membership oracle could be converted to a sequence generator, but this looping costs bytes to implement that shouldn't be "free".

Answer (score 0):

### This is a good default

This output method is very similar to outputting the \$n\$-th value in a sequence.

If you implement a function `f` which returns the \$n\$-th value in the sequence, then the sequence is `map(f, integers)`. If `f` is a membership oracle, the sequence is `filter(f, integers)`. I think the difference between a map over the integers and a filter over them is small enough that if we allow one we should allow the other, unless the writer explicitly excludes it.

Another perspective to this similarity is the operations: outputting the \$n\$-th value in the sequence, compared to outputting the \$n\$-th value in the indicator sequence. A strictly increasing integer sequence and its indicator sequence are very closely tied, so I think both output methods should be allowed. In fact, this even suggests a broadening of the suggestion — answers can choose whether to output the sequence or the indicator sequence, using any of the default methods for either, although that's a discussion for another time.